# Elegant way to print formatted list together with index values in python?

Tags: python, numpy, formatting, pretty-print

While there are a few questions and answers out there which come close to what I am looking for, I am wondering if there isn't a more elegant solution to this specific problem: I have a numpy (2D) array and want to print it row by row together with the row number up front - and of course nicely formatted.

This code does the printing, straightforward but without formatting:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((2,3))
for i in range(2):
    print i, A[i]
```

I can also produce formatted output by building the formatted string anew in each line:

```
for i in range(2):
    print "%4i "%(i)+" ".join(["%6.2f"%(v) for v in A[i]])
```

While this works, I figured it may be more readable and perhaps more efficient(?) to build the format string only once and then "paste" the numbers in for each line:

```
NVAR=A.shape[1]
fmt = "%4i" + NVAR*"  %6.2f"
for i in range(2):
    print fmt % (i, A[i])
```

This fails, because the formatted print expects a tuple with float elements, but A[i] is an ndarray. Thus, my questions really boils down to "How can I form a tuple out of an integer value and a 1-D ndarray?". I did try:

```
    tuple( [i].extend([v for v in A[i]]) )
```

but that doesn't work (this expression yields None, even though `[v for v in A[i]]` works correctly).

Or am I only still too much thinking FORTRAN here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the array elements directly to a tuple using the `tuple` constructor :

```
for i in range(2):
    print fmt % ((i, ) + tuple(A[i]))
```

Here, `+` represents tuple concatenation.

Also, if you're coming from FORTRAN you might not yet know about [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), which can be handy for this type of loop operation :

```
for i, a in enumerate(A):
    print fmt % ((i, ) + tuple(a))
```

You could combine this with [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to flatten the pairs from enumerate :

```
import itertools

for i, a in enumerate(A):
    print fmt % tuple(itertools.chain((i, ), a))
```

These are all probably overkill for what you're trying to do here, but I just wanted to show a few more ways of doing it.

Comment: This answer seems to ignore the fact that the format string `fmt` needs to change depending on the number of elements in `A[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the numpy array to a list with `tolist()` first.

```
for i in range(2):
    print fmt % tuple([i] + A[i].tolist())
```

The reason for your error is that extending a list yields no return value.

```
>>> x = range(5)
>>> x.extend([5, 6])
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The `+` operator is for concatenation of lists.

Comment: This is easy and clear - however, I chose to "accept" the third answer, because it avoids one datatype (lists) and directly concatenates tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(200,3)
for i in xrange(98, 102):
    print '{0:4d} {1}'.format(i, A[i]) #'4d' reserves space for 4 digits
                                       # Modify to the maximum # of rows
```

The output looks like:

```
  98 [ 0.40745341  0.29954899  0.21880649]
  99 [ 0.23325155  0.81340095  0.57966024]
 100 [ 0.24145552  0.12387366  0.0384011 ]
 101 [ 0.76432552  0.68382022  0.93935336]
```